# Is there a proper pattern to mix different types in a GraphQLUnionType?

Tags: graphql

I have a problem where I need to create a query that will return different possible types for a node, I am also exploiting the __typename property to determine which one I received.

The reason I am not using an EnumType is because the different subtypes can be vastly different.

A few of them are empty (e.g. they do not possess any properties).

This causes a problem because I cannot create a UnionType.

I tried to use ScalarTypes for these empty definitions, but for Union I can only use ObjectTypes, which require a 'fields' definition.

For example, here are some definitions of classes I used from the service side

```
classA {
token: string
}

classB {
}

classC {
}
type returnType = classA | classB | classC
```

For each of those I define a type

```
typeA = GraphQLObjectType ofType classA with fields => {token}
typeB = GraphQLObjectType ofType classB with fields => undefined
typeC = GraphQLObjectType ofType classC with fields => undefined
```

The problem occurs when building union type for the query

```
new GraphQLUnionType({
      types: [typeA, typeB, typeC]
})
```

I would like to know what's the proper way of dealing with this scenario, from a client I'd simply like to do something like

```
query {
   myquery {
     mode: __typename
     ... typeA {
         token
     }
  }
```

I tried to inject the name as a property, and this works because every type will have one, but this is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably work around this by adding some field to the otherwise-empty object types.

```graphql
"""Objects of this type don't have properties."""
type classB {
  """Just a placeholder value; always null."""
  _placeholder: Bool
}
```

Once you have that it can participate in the union type normally, and you can query its `__typename` as normal.  You don't specifically have to mention it in the query if you don't want to.

```graphql
query {
  myquery {
    __typename
    ... on classA {
      token
    }
    # No need for a fragment ...on classB
  }
}
```

Comment: In the end this is what I did, thanks for your input